# Update textbox from 1st UpdatePanel using LinkButton from 2nd UpdatePanel's gridview. Control could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, triggers, updatepanel

I need to add the LinkButton `btnAddRow` in UpdatePanel `upSectionB` but the problem is I'm having this error during load:

> A control with ID 'btnAddRow' could not be found for the trigger in
>   UpdatePanel 'upSectionB'.

My simplified aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSectionB" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        Request Budget (USD)
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddRow" EventName="Click" />
        //Poses problems when I uncomment the trigger above. btnAddRow is a LinkButton inside upSectionC
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSectionC" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvCostBreakdown" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BudgetUSD") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmountTotal" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteRow" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete" OnClick="btnDeleteRow_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id","{0}") %>' OnClientClick="">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddRow" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="vgAddRow" ToolTip="Add Row" OnClick="btnAddRow_Click">Add Row</asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is trigger the Update of `upSectionB` when `btnAddRow` is clicked.

```
protected void btnAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTotal.Text = "new value";

    //update the other updatepanel
    upSectionB.Update();
}
```

The reason you get that error is because the button is in a GridView Control and therefore not accessible in the scope of the aspx page. If you wanted to do something with the button in the Footer, you need to use FindControl.

```
LinkButton lb = gvCostBreakdown.FooterRow.FindControl("btnAddRow") as LinkButton;
```

Comment: Can't believe it was just one line of code that I'm missing. This worked! Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (Reason why this error occurs as your LinkButton is inside GridView which will not be triggered outside the GridView) and fixed it following below steps:

**Step 1:** Add a RowCommand event in your GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCostBreakdown" OnRowCommand="gvCostBreakdown_RowCommand" ...
```

**Step 2:** Add CommandName property in your LinkButton inside your GridView:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddRow" CommandName="AddRow" ...
```

**Step 3:** Remove `UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` in your first UpdatePanel (`upSectionB`) give ControlID as `gvCostBreakdown` and EventName as `RowCommand` of `<Triggers>`:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvCostBreakdown" EventName="RowCommand" />
</Triggers>
```

**Step 4:** Finally, in RowCommand event set the TextBox value from GridView row:

```
// Getting GridView row which clicked
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

// Check if LinkButton (AddRow) is clicked
if (e.CommandName=="AddRow")
{
    // getting the value of label inside GridView
    string rowCellValue = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;

    // setting value to TextBox which is inside First UpdatePanel
    txtTotal.Text = rowCellValue;
}
```

See full example below:

**Code-Behind:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // adding dummy data into DataTable
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        dt.Rows.Add("Row1");
        dt.Rows.Add("Row2");
    }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // setting and binding DataTable to GridView
        gvCostBreakdown.DataSource = dt;
        gvCostBreakdown.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void gvCostBreakdown_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Getting GridView row which clicked
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

    // Check if LinkButton (AddRow) is clicked
    if (e.CommandName=="AddRow")
    {
        // getting the value of label inside GridView
        string rowCellValue = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;

        // setting value to TextBox which is inside First UpdatePanel
        txtTotal.Text = rowCellValue;
    }
}
```

**.Aspx Code:**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSectionB" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        TextBox:
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvCostBreakdown" EventName="RowCommand" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSectionC" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        GridView: </b>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvCostBreakdown" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvCostBreakdown_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column2">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddRow" CommandName="AddRow" runat="server">Add Row</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**.GIF Image Demo:**

[image]